# I need to find my Instagram User ID

Tags: instagram-api

Im using the Ella theme for my shopify store and need to find my Instgram User ID, all the websites I have visited no longer work to retrieve my Instagram User ID and unsure how to find it to be able to pull in my instagram feed to my webiste

Answer (score 4):

[Update]

The below answer still holds true. However, you only need step one to get your userId. If you have an access token, the digits before the first dot should be your userId. If your access token is `111111111.2222222.33333333333333333333333333333333` your userId should be `111111111`.

Thank you [Andrew Fraser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6466600/andrew-fraser) for pointing this out.

---

Documentation (instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/) states that using the endpoint https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN a user can get this information.

To accomplish this, you will need to jump through a few hoops. These steps are listed below. Essentially, you will need to create an app under the account you need the userId for. Then you will need to use information such as the client id and redirect uri to receive an access token. Once you have obtained an access token you can use this to request the user id.

How to do this?

1. Get an `Access Token` for the user you wish to get information about.

   - First, you need to get your `Client ID` and associated app `Redirect URI`.
   - Login as the Account you want to create an Access Token for.
   - Go to instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/ and create an App for what you want to do. This will give you a `Client ID` and setup a `Redirect URI`.
   - Since we will be using Implicit OAuth you will also need to enable this for the app you are using. To do so, click `Edit Client` and choose the tab `Security`. There should be a check box for `Disable implicit OAuth`. Uncheck this box to enable Implicit OAuth.
   - In a web browser (preferably Chrome), visit `https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=token`.
   - In the URL, replace CLIENT-ID and REDIRECT-URI with the information from the app you created.
   - This will return a URL. Your new access token will be a query param on the URL.
2. Visit /user/self/ endpoint to get user info.

   - In a web browser (preferably Chrome), visit `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN` and replace `ACCESS-TOKEN` with the hash you received from step one.
   - This should return a JSON object. One of the properties in this object is your userId.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this website - http://www.instaid.co.uk

Or you can do the following replacing {username} with your Instagram username

https://www.instagram.com/{username}/?__a=1

Answer (score 1):

The answer listed works, but a quicker way is, if you get an access token, the number at the beginning of the token (before the dot) is your user ID.

Answer (score 0):

I always use https://www.thekeygram.com/find-instagram-user-id/ to find my instagram User ID